# Disable filter button if no data

Tags: jquery, filtering

I would like to know how to disable a filter button (add `class "disabled"`) if there is no corresponding data.

Here is my current code below. In this example, if there is no data for "`Category 2"`, I would like to add the class `"is-none"` to the filter button.

Thank you for your help!

```js
   
/* Shows and hides filtered items. */
$(".filter-simple-button").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  if (value === "all") {
    $('.filter-simple-item').show('1000');
  } else {
    $(".filter-simple-item").not('.' + value).hide('3000');
    $('.filter-simple-item').filter('.' + value).show('3000');
  }
});

/* Changes active class on filter buttons */
$('.filter-simple-button').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('is-active');
  $(this).addClass('is-active');
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-group">
  <button class="button filter-simple-button is-active" data-filter="all">All items</button>
<button class="button hollow filter-simple-button" data-filter="category-1">Category 1</button>
<button class="button hollow filter-simple-button" data-filter="category-2">Category 2</button>
<button class="button hollow filter-simple-button" data-filter="category-3">Category 3</button>
</div>

<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
<div class="filter-simple-item category-1">
Post #1 in Category 1 
</div>
<div class="filter-simple-item category-1">
Post #2 in Category 1
</div>
<div class="filter-simple-item category-3">
Post #3 in Category 3
</div>
<div class="filter-simple-item category-1">
Post #4 in Category 1 
</div>
```

Comment: Please complete the snippet I made for you

Comment: How exactly do you determine there 'is not data' for the button? You seem to be missing the important part of your HTML. Also note that you can join those separate click event handlers in to one

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your replies. I updated the snippet. In this example, I want to apply a particular "disabled" class to the "Category 2" button because it does not return any post.

Answer (score 0):

```
    There you go with the correct snippet. 

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button class="button filter-simple-button is-active" data-filter="all">All items</button>
    <button class="button hollow filter-simple-button" data-filter="category-1">Category 1</button>
    <button class="button hollow filter-simple-button" data-filter="category-2">Category 2</button>
    <button class="button hollow filter-simple-button" data-filter="category-3">Category 3</button>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
    <div class="filter-simple-item category-1">
    Post #1 in Category 1 
    </div>
    <div class="filter-simple-item category-1">
    Post #2 in Category 1
    </div>
    <div class="filter-simple-item category-3">
    Post #3 in Category 3
    </div>
    <div class="filter-simple-item category-1">
    Post #4 in Category 1 
    </div>


    /* Shows and hides filtered items. */
    $(".filter-simple-button").click(function() {
      var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      if (value === "all") {
        $('.filter-simple-item').show('1000');
      } else {
        $(".filter-simple-item").not('.' + value).hide('3000');
        $('.filter-simple-item').filter('.' + value).show('3000');
      }
    });

    /* Changes active class on filter buttons */
    $('.filter-simple-button').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('is-active');
      $(this).addClass('is-active');
    if (!$(this).hasClass("category-2")){
        $(this).addClass("is-none");
    }
    });
    Let me know if it solves the issue.

https://codepen.io/niazi71/pen/vpPJBg
```